# Named Credential

Tags: salesforce, integration

I want to access the URL of the named credential and want to dynamically add some query parameters to it. Is it possible? Like in case of custom settings I access the value by get values directly. Does the named credential global variable credential provides me any such opportunity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the documentation here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm

This example is used:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:***My_Named_Credential***/some_path');
```

As long as your named credential URL contains the protocol, subdomain (if required), hostname and port (id required) then you can append the path, parameters or fragments.

For example:

```
Map<String, String> urlParameters = new Map<String, String>{'client_id','12345'};
String urlParameterString = '';
for (String param : urlParameters.keySet()) {
    urlParameterString += param+'='+urlParameters.get(param);
}

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(
    String.format(
        'callout:GoogleAPI/{0}?{1}#{2}',
        new String[]{'oauth2', urlParameterString, 'anchorId'}
    )
);
```

If the named credential URL was:

`https://api.google.com`

That endpoint should then be something like this:

`https://api.google.com/oauth2?client_id=12345#anchorId`

Comment: Hi Tiaan, I tried it in the aforementioned way but it's not working. In my case I am having  a named credential namely ProjectService and I am eager to access the url parameter from that named credential in the suggested way of your's its not working. Please note the syntax String.format(
        'callout:ProjectService/{0}?{1}#{2}',
        new String[]{ urlParameterString, 'anchorId'}
    )

Comment: Hi @user9207683 in your Syntax you are declaring 2 parameters to be replaced in the template string but you actually declare 3 parameters in the template string `{0}`, `{1}` and `{2}`. To make this work properly change the template string to: `'callout:ProjectService/?{0}#{1}'`